# changing the original list inside function

Tags: python, python-2.7, duplicates

in need to create one function that once remove duplicates while not changing the original list.
and in the second one it needs to change the original list and return nothing .
the problem here that the second function  just works on one repeat and doesnt work on 2 different numbers( it just removes one number ( it doesnt work on [2,3,4,5,3,4] but works [ 1,2,3,3]

```
def drop_duplicates(lst):
    s = []
    # Write the rest of the code for question 3a below here.
    for i in lst:
       if i not in s:
           s.append(i)
    return s
lst = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2]
print drop_duplicates(lst)
print lst

def drop_duplicates_in_place(lst):
    # Write the rest of the code for question 3b below here.
    for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
        for j in range ( i+1, len(lst) - 1):
            if lst[i] == lst[j]:
                lst.pop(j)
            else:
                continue

lst = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2] 
print lst
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop range is too short:

```
for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(lst)):  # no -1 here
```

Furthermore, you do not really need the `else` part in your loop body. Generally, nested loops and the repeated removing from (the middle) of a list are not ideal performance-wise. The recommended way too remove duplicates while maintaining order of occurrence in linear is by using an `collections.OrderedDict`. To make it in-place, you can use slice assignment:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def drop_duplicates_in_place(lst):
    lst[:] = OrderedDict.fromkeys(lst)
```

Comment: @sereenmasalha For interests sake, this works in python 3.6+ without the import as dicts are ordered by default. `lst[:] = dict.fromkeys(lst)`